# Failed to activate extension: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/environments'

Tags: networking, visual-studio-code, ibm-server

I've been trying to run the IBM Blockchain network test on my new Mac, however, every time I pull up Visual Studio and click on the box, I get this exact error message but I don't understand it, could anyone give guidance? Has anyone else had this problem, I've scoured the internet but haven't found a solution that works.
Thanks, 
Anthony Caesar